# Twitter Boootstrap column width depending on width of parent container

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one control that might appear either in main content or in side bar:

```
<main id="main-content" class="col-md-8">
    <div id="mycontrol" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">..</div>
</div>
<aside id="sidebar" class="col-md-4">
    <div id="mycontrol" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">..</div>
</div>
```

So here I need "mycontrol" to fill the width of sidebar, but only half width of main-content.

I had the understanding that "mycontrol" will use "col-md-6" for medium container and "col-sm-12" for small container. But in my case the sidebar with is samll (less than 768px), yet it's filling half the width of sidebar.

I tried to wrap the sidebar with `<div class='container'></div>` but it didn't work, And "mycontrol" appears half width in both main content and side bar.

[image]

As you can see in the screen shot. I the control appears filling half the column width in both cases. I want the width to be 50% in main content, but 100% in side bar, but using the same css class definition.

**Edit:**

I know I can use differnt class names depending on the desired width. But I can't since "mycontrol" is a reusable control.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, can you post a screenshot or a fiddle to get you better??

Comment: The page is complex and it's in asp.net. I thought explanation was clear. I need to add the div "mycontrol" inside "main-content" and "sidebar" using the same hypertext including css class as shown above. Now my problem is that "mycontrol" with is always half of container. even though width of "sidebar" with is less than 768px.

Comment: Please see the printscreen. It's not easy to put the  content in js fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem, make sure to override bootstrap.

html:

```
<main id="main-content" class="col-md-8">
    <div id="mycontrol" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">..</div>
</div>
<aside id="sidebar" class="col-md-4">
    <div id="mycontrol" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">..</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#sidebar #mycontrol {width: 100%;}
#main-content #mycontrol {width: 50%;}
```

Comment: I was hoping that boostrap has something to address this issue. I mean in that case I won't be able to use the "col-*" class.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be helpful if you can add a Fiddle.  What I'm taking form your post is that you are looking for your content to be 100% width of the  or 50% width of the  tag.

You would need to override the bootstrap classes to accomplish what you are looking for.  You can do this by either adding the following CSS which will target the specific mycontrol that you are looking for and sets its div appropriately.

```
#sidebar #mycontrol {width: 100%;}
#main-content #mycontrol {width: 50%;}
```

Alternatively, you can also add a customized class to the fist div and set the width within that class.

HTML:

```
<main id="main-content" class="col-md-8">
    <div id="mycontrol" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 setWidthTo50">..</div>
</div>
<aside id="sidebar" class="col-md-4">
    <div id="mycontrol" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">..</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.setWidthTo50 { width: 50% }
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult because the page is very complex, I tried to abstract it. Now I need to use the same hypertext for both places, including the class. "mycontrol" is actually an include.